# Samsung Galaxy S10 automatically deleting emails using email app

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S10, and it is automatically deleting emails using the email app.

What do I have to do to keep emails from being deleted?

Comment: Are you sure the emails are deleted and not just not displayed? Usually mail programs only show the mails received in the last ~14 days. Older mails are not displayed but they are not deleted.

Comment: They are in the inbox but after something they are are not there

Comment: Then the mails are not deleted, just not displayed. Open the settings of the app, select your account and change the value how many days are synchronized. As I don't have a Samsung device I can't tell you the exact names and the way to this setting.

Comment: the menus must be different . your suggestions don't seem to match the S10 , TKS ANYWAY,